# Phonegap application that loads an external link on startup - Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm creating a phonegap application that links to a website, which I want to load when the page is started up.

Here is what I've tried, a simple onload method calling a window.open function and I've tried a function that is called when the device is ready. I'm running the latest version of Phonegap, which is 3.5.0 and an Android HTC One running 4.4.2. Below is my code for deviceready. This code is within the index.html code, in the www folder within my Durandal applcation. I believe it's not working because I don't have the cordova.js file which is imported in the example code at this link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/durandal/css/durandal.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
            function onLoad () {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
                    window.open("http://google.com", "_system");
                }, false);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad">
        <div id="applicationHost"></div>
        <script src="lib/require/require.js" data-main="app/main"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help. This is my first stack overflow question. Please tell me if my question format isn't right and how I can improve it for future questions. Also, please suggest other ways that I can open a window on app start up using phonegap. Another option I've considered is developing an app with Android and Java, create a WebView, but that doesn't give me the cross platform deployment I want for Android and Windows Phone and I'd like to write this simple app using HTML,CSS, JS using Durandal, and PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line just after durandal.css addition link.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Without cordova.js deviceready function won't fire. You don't need to see right now where is that cordova.js. It'll be added automatically by phonegap. Right now just add this line.